# Sending Dynamic NdefRecords to the constructor

Tags: java, android, nfc

im trying to build an application using NFC to passes data between phones through NFC tag.
but there's one thing that bothers me is that how can I send various size of record into the constructor ? 
For example, this constructor only accept 2 NDEFRecord.

```
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{
            NfcUtils.createRecord(MIME_TYPE, text.getBytes()),
            NfcUtils.createRecord(MIME_TYPE, text.getBytes()),
            NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord(TARGET_APPLICATION)
    });
```

My application may send various records but the constructor seems accept 'static' records.

I apologize for any mistake / inconvenience that may caused. 
I hope that you all get what I'm trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NdefMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html#NdefMessage(android.nfc.NdefRecord,%20android.nfc.NdefRecord...)) constructor can take as many NdefRecords as you want.

```
NdefRecord first = NdefRecord.createUri("http://stackoverflow.com/");
NdefRecord second = NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", "content".getBytes());
NdefRecord third = NdefRecord.createExternal("com.stackoverflow", "nfc", "content".getBytes());
// and so on ...

NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(first, second, third);
```

If you want to add records dynamically, you can fill a NdefRecord array and pass it as an argument.

```
NdefRecord[] records = new NdefRecord[3];
records[0] = NdefRecord.createUri("http://stackoverflow.com/");
records[1] = NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", "content".getBytes());
records[2] = NdefRecord.createExternal("com.stackoverflow", "nfc", "content".getBytes());

NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
```

Comment: Thank you ! it worked ! :D
And I have 1 more questions 
I encountered the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562374/automatically-reading-data-from-nfc-tag
But i couldn't comment, should i open a new thread? or i can just ask here?

Comment: You need at least 50 reputation to post comments: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment
Either ask here or open new question.